# IE11 jQuery html() does not function inside SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, svg, safari

Works in Chrome, etc.

Screenshot should explain the situation.

The SVG's content has been changed in the DOM, but the 'DOM Explorer' is reporting the original rect is still there (it's being shown).

Interestingly enough, Safari 7 on OS X also exhibits the same behavior.

[image]

Comment: On IE innerHTML creates elements in the html namespace as opposed to the svg namespace. You might try DOMParser instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser but you'll need to put an SVG namespace on the root element you want to parse.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

A quick fix is to use jQuery empty() instead of html('');

e.g.,

```
var svg = d3.selectAll("svg");
svg.each(function() {
    // does not work in IE $(this).html('');
    $(this).empty();
});
```